# Set custom range for y axis in R plotly

Tags: r, charts, plotly

Simple question, but I've been trying fruitlessly for the better part of an hour.

I have a scatter chart built with the plotly package in R. The vertical axis of this chart is logarithmic, and I want to set the range of the y axis to reach from 0 to 1E7 with ticks every every 10^i. How do I do this?

Comment: totally misread that its in plotly. sorry cant help you there: google: `axis ticks in r plotly` and `logarithmic axis r plotly` should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

A bit hacky, but the trick is to add a data point outside of the x domain and at the y max you desire. You can additionally use `showlegend = F` to hide it from the legend.

`p <- add_trace(p, x = list(-1), y = list(1E7), name = " ", showlegend = F)`

My x axis' domain goes from 1 to 1000, so by adding the point at x = -1, it is effectively hidden from the chart.